# How to Draw a line on chart without a plot point using chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using chart.js line chart. I can use the chart correctly but if I have only one plot point then the chart doesn't create a line from start to that point. I want to draw a line from the start of the chart to that single plot point without placing a plot point on that first day as we don't have data in the database for it.

Current chart behaviour:

[image]

Need a line like drawn here from the start of the chart:

[image]

Is this possible to draw a line on the chart from start to that point? Maybe some start point property or a hidden x-axis attribute on the chart to achieve this?

Also, any possible way to remove that space from top before that "Extreme" point on Y-Axis?

I have done hard research on it, have read the docs multiple times but unable to achieve them.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you tried Area charts with fill set to false? Check out the samples here https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/line-boundaries.html</strike>

It's kind of a hack but you can append the data with an extra point and update its styles to keep it hidden, Refer to our fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hpdr5jf1/

Relative code

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["", "Actual Data"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data Point',
          data: [12, 12],
        pointRadius: [0],
        pointHitRadius: [0],
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'red'
        }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Comment: Yes, but it needs a starting data point to draw a line from the start as you can see in the example but I don't want to place a starting point as there is no actual data for it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of points but only want to draw the lines between them without displaying the individual points, you can achieve this by setting the pointRadius and pointHoverRadius properties to 0 in the dataset options. This will effectively hide the points while still drawing the lines connecting them. Here's how you can do it:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My Line',
            data: [
                {x: 0, y: 100},
                // Add your other data points here...
                {x: 800, y: 300}
            ],
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', // Red color
            borderWidth: 2, // Line width
            pointRadius: 0, // Hide points
            pointHoverRadius: 0 // Hide points on hover
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom'
            },
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```